# How can I add 2 separate backgrounds in html?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a website where when it loads, there is a full screen image, and when you scroll down it has a white background which includes all of my about and contact information. How can I do it? I made a div called "top-background" which includes the source to the image, and in the css i used

```css
z-index: -100;
height: 30%;
width: 100%;
top: 0%;
```

But it doesn't fullscreen or do what i want it to do.

Comment: Something like this? https://www.rahicodes.tk/

Comment: Yeah like that.

Comment: You could use `vh` & `vw` units to defined to always make it till the entire screen for all users. Read up on units here - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a div 100% height of the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.bgone {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: blue;
    background-image: url('yourimagehere.png');
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
}

.bgtwo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bgone'>On page load content</div>
<div class='bgtwo'>Scrolled content</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating two `div`'s and making their height `100vh` which stands for 100% of view height.

```css
.background-1 {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}

.background-2 {
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-1"></div>
<div class="background-2"></div>
```